# Check user value is present in given array

Tags: javascript

As you can see in below code. I'm trying to check whether `mergeUserArray` value is present in `winArray` or not. But I'm not able to achieve it.

Because I want, if any other number is in `mergeUserArray` it should match if three number combination present in it. Like 789 is present in 7189.

I tried regular expression too but it also didn't work.
`let regxWinArray = /(123)|(456)|(789)/g;`

```js
let winArray = [123,456,789];
// let mergeUserArray = [789];  --Value matched
 let mergeUserArray = [7189]; // Value didn't match
  if(winArray.includes(Number(mergeUserArray))){
    console.log("Number matched");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Number not matched");
  }
```

Comment: am i understanding this correctly? you're trying to check if any value from the winArray is a substring of the number within the (for some reason) single value array?

Comment: is mergeUserArray.length always going to be 1 ?

Comment: @DanteDX Yes, it will be always 1. But it will consist of some other values in between actual combinations.

Comment: @digitalniweb Please try to read the question carefully first, before posting any comments & suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear whether order of numbers should match. Added both options to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global regex character match and check whether number of found characters match:

```js
let winArray = [123, 456, 789];

// let mergeUserArray = [789];  --Value matched
let mergeUserArray = [7189]; // Value didn't match

let match = winArray.some(item => mergeUserArray.some(what => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${item}]`, 'g');
    return what.toString().match(regex)?.length === item.toString().length;
}));

console.log(match);
```

If the order of characters should match:

```js
let winArray = [123, 456, 789];

const hasMatch = mergeUserArray => winArray.some(item => mergeUserArray.some(what => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${item}]`, 'g');
    return what.toString().match(regex)?.join('') === item.toString();
}));

console.log([7189], hasMatch([7189]));
console.log([1897], hasMatch([1897]));
```

If we need all values in `mergeUserArray` matched:

```js
let winArray = [123, 456, 789];

let mergeUserArray = [7189, 654]; 

let match = mergeUserArray.every(what => winArray.some(item => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[${item}]`, 'g');
    return what.toString().match(regex)?.length === item.toString().length;
}));

console.log(match);
```

Comment: What if winArray has duplicate values?

Comment: @mr.Hritik the duplicate values won't be processed. if any first values match in both arrays it will return `true`. if you want match all values in `mergeUserArray` we need to change `some` to `every`, adding it to the answer

Comment: @mr.Hritik added to the asnwer

Comment: @mr.Hritik you are welcome :) you could also upvote my detailed answer (the arrow up), thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
let winArray = [123, 456, 789];
let mergeUserArray = [7189];
let matchFound = false;

for (let i = 0; i < mergeUserArray.length; i++) {
  const num = mergeUserArray[i].toString();
  if (num.length >= 3) {
    for (let j = 0; j < num.length - 2; j++) {
      const combination = num.substr(j, 3);
      if (winArray.includes(Number(combination))) {
        matchFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (matchFound) {
  console.log("Number matched");
} else {
  console.log("Number not matched");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
let winArray = [789, 456, , 123];
let mergeUserArray = [7189];
let matchFound = false;

for (let item of winArray) {
    for (let item2 of mergeUserArray) {
        if (item && item.toString().localeCompare(item2.toString()) > -1) {
            console.log(`${item} is matched with ${item2}`)
            matchFound = true;
        } else {
            console.log('Not matched')
        }
    }
```